# Find limits of integration for the interior region of sphere with center $(a,0,0)$ and radius $a$ using spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

I am asked to find limits of integration for the interior region of sphere with center $(a,0,0)$ and radius $a$ using spherical coordinates. How can one do that?

I know that one may use

$$
x = r \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi)\\
y = r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi)\\
z = r \cos(\phi)
$$

Is it possible do to the same with cylindrical coordinates?

Thank you.

Comment: What if you recenter the origin? Just rename the x-coordinate, and redefine the function to be integrated in the new coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a few choices.

rectangular:

$(x-a)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2\\
x^2 + y^2 + z$ = 2ax$

Spherical... since x is the "special one", I would suggest.

$$x = r \cos(\phi)\\
y = r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi)\\
z = r \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi)$$

Plug these into your equation for the sphere and,
$r^2 = 2a\,r\cos\phi $
$r$ will range from $0$ to $2a\cos\phi, \theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi, \phi$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$

If you went with the traditional.

$$x =r \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi)\\
y = r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi)\\
z =  r \cos(\phi)$$

Then $r$ will range from $0$ to $2a\cos\theta\sin\phi, \theta$ from$-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$

how about...Taking the traditional and translating it.

$$x =r \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) + a\\
y = r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi)\\
z =  r \cos(\phi)$$

And $r$ goes from $0$ to $a.$

Cylindrical.

$$x = x+a\\
y = r \sin(\theta)\\
z = r \cos(\theta)$$

x from $-\sqrt {a^2-r^2}$ to $\sqrt {a^2-r^2}$

or,

$$x = x\\
y = r \sin(\theta)\\
z = r \cos(\theta)$$

x from $a-\sqrt {a^2-r^2}$ to $a+\sqrt {a^2-r^2}$

etc.

Comment: Thats great Doug! Thank you! Can I ask you something? Do you mind looking into this question I've posted? Thanks! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792439/evaluating-the-integral-of-fx-y-z-fracy-sqrtz-on-y-geq-0-0-leq